# Turning on Loads caused an Increase in Alternator Base Voltage

Tags: alternator

I've been having some strange [low voltage problems lately](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/20914/battery-light-wont-go-off-since-changing-battery).  I was messing around, and decided to turn on as many electrical loads as I could, which meant the radio, high beam headlights, defroster, and fan blower.  Before doing that my check battery light was on and I was reading about 13.75 volts on my multi-meter.  Turning all these loads on caused my voltage to drop to about 11.8 volts, however, after turning all the loads off I noticed that my check battery light was off and that my base voltage had jumped to about 14.05 volts at idle.

Does anyone have any idea what just happened?

Comment: I'd want to know what open-circuit battery voltage is in the morning, and immediately after a 15 minute highway drive.  Those things would suggest whether the issue is a bad battery, or a bad alternator (with, i'm assuming, a built-in voltage regulator which would be the *real* culprit)

Comment: @SteveRacer Battery is almost new, just bought it a few months ago.  I'm not sure if voltage regulation in my car is done by an external regulator or by the ECU.  It's a 98 Mazda 626 GF 2L.

Comment: I still don't have a clue why your battery light would come on at 13.75v ... this should be plenty fine to keep the battery charged. Does the voltage rise when you rev the engine a little? If there is a problem, I'd suggest it's with the regulator due to not keeping up with demand when the load is put on it. Jumping up in voltage is fairly normal after a big load. This is to recharge the battery.

Comment: How many wires on the alternator plug? 3 wire systems are ecu controlled.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2  If I rev the engine without any loads on the voltage stay constant, if I rev it with all loads turned on it rises.  Maybe I'll put up a graph later from my log data.

Comment: @Ben  According to the 97 EU WSM it's a two pin connector.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 While the 97 EU WSM just says voltage should be between 13-15v at idle, the 98 US WSM specifies 13.5v at idle.  This is getting weirder and weirder.

Comment: I would also check all related connection quality and cleanliness.  Where the battery indicator and where you hooked up the multimeter  are likely two different locations -- with potential losses due to corrosion and gobbledegooks...

Comment: And do a voltage drop test while running with your meter on all battery connections - D+ heavy alternator wire, frame to battery post negative, starter cable, and the smaller wire at B+ if it's seperate from the the starter main.  Nothing more that a few tenths of a volt is acceptable.  On a '98 car it's quite possible one or more cables are corroded under the insulation.

Comment: @Ben  Mine is the Mitsubishi DP style, with two wires, but it's still ECU controlled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had what appears to have been a [faulty field control unit on my alternator](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/34966/7132).  Voltage regulation is done by the ECU via the field control unit.  I changed the alternator and now every thing's OK.